# How do I count the number of occurrences of distinct values when they are separated by commas

Tags: database, ms-access

the values for 3 cells within my column could look like this

```
1st cell:(3hew, i-88dds, o8-ku4)
2nd cell:(4ijk, l-45dms, o9-dj4)
3rd cell:(g8ew, r-7dnns, o9-dj4)
```

if there are multiple values in a cell then they are separated by a trailing comma. in this case there are 2 values that occur more then once (o9-dj4), so this would be flagged as a multiple occurrence. so, my counter would read 1 so far. how would i implement this in an Access query?

I was told to use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to pull the values into a temp table then count the number of distinct occurrences from the temp table, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union query:

```
SELECT Mid([Cell],2,4) AS CellOne
FROM TableCell
UNION
SELECT Mid([Cell],8,7) AS CellOne
FROM TableCell
UNION
SELECT Mid([Cell],17,6) AS CellOne
FROM TableCell
```

Returns:

```
CellOne
-------
3hew
4ijk
g8ew
i-88dds
l-45dms
o8-ku4
o9-dj4
r-7dnns
```